# remove activity feed from Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, function, admin

I am looking for a way to hide activity feed from the dashboard using a function. Does anyone know how to do this? I want to completely remove it. I want to achieve this without a plugin.

Comment: ["Without a plugin" is a myth](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php), you'll have to write your own mini-plugin to do that. The answer is in [this search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=disable+dashboard+widget).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll either have to create a plugin or add a function to your theme functions.php file.

```
function remove_activity_dashboard_widget() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'side' );
} 

// Hook into the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action to register our function
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_activity_dashboard_widget' );
```

Here is the codex page on the subject:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets

Comment: On latest wp, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [remove_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) like;

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets(){
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

add above code to `functions.php`

Comment: On latest wp, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MichaelRogers works as expected on latest wp (4.9.6 right now)!

Answer (score 2):

Dashboard widgets and other meta boxes can also be removed by using the `unset` function. You might need to play around with the array keys, or use `var_dump()` to find the path for the widget you're looking for.

```
 // Removes dashboard activity widget.
  function remove_dashboard_activity_widget() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_activity']);
  }

  // Triggers dashboard widgets removal.
  add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_activity_widget');
```

Additionally like [Hüseyin BABAL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1796105/h%C3%BCseyin-babal) mentioned, meta boxes can also be removed like this:

```
function remove_dashboard_widgets(){
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets');
```